# how to import module using '@' symbol, Node+Express+Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I am relatively new to Node+Typescript, I have a file which import another file module using like this `import { IS_PRODUCTION } from '@/config/config';`, I cant understand how it is imported by `@` symbol.

Need some help in understanding this.

Thanks

[EDIT]: this is tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es2018",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "build",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"],
      "@@/*": ["./*"]
    },
    "module": "commonjs",
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["build", "node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: It should be a scope `@scope/` as mentioned [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html)

Comment: You probably have a bundler tool that converts this prefix (usually to project root), e.g. if you use a framework that builds your app. TS is also very probably configured to understand the prefix in its `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: Or your project is using an [import map](https://github.com/WICG/import-maps)

Comment: `@` is valid in a module specifier and a valid character in Windows, Mac, and Linux file names.

Answer (score 12):

Your `tsconfig.json` has some custom paths setup. One of them is this:

```
"@/*": ["./src/*"],
```

That means that when typescript sees a path that starts with `@/whatever` then it translates that to `path/of/tsconfig/here/src/whatever`.

It's nice because it allows you load files with paths from the root of the project. That way if you move a file you don't have to change all the imports.

You can read about this feature in [the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping)